# NOMAD error: No nodes were eligible for evaluation

Tags: nomad

My Nomad job is intermittently failing with the following error:

Placement Failure
Task Group "*jobnamewashere*":

- No nodes were eligible for evaluation

I can find no further errors in the the nomad logs or anywhere else. Is there a way to find out what placement constraint was violated?

Answer (score 0):

> what placement constraint was violated?

No, not really.

I think this would be a nice feature request - indeed, the constraints - datacenters, node type, node pool, constraint1, constraint2, etc., memory, cpu - have to be evaluated in order.

If this is the first message, most probably you mixed datacenter or node type.